# Specific Excel Formula doesn't works

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to make an text string from 7 second last numbers of EAN and additional string..

EAN is here: 8592346106093, so the string what I need is: MJ4610609

I also tried by idea from this article: https://excelnotes.com/how-to-extract-the-second-last-letter/ but doesn't works.. Can anyone help me?

I also tried to setup the columns to General format, text format and number, nothing doesn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to [Mark Pattison's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63683849/9290986):

```
="MJ" & LEFT(RIGHT(A1,8),7)
```

This will give you the leftmost 7 of the rightmost 8 characters of the value in cell A1, prepended with the string "MJ"

Comment: Thank you! You've helped me so much.

Answer (score 2):

If the number 8592346106093 is in cell A1, the the following formula will work:

```
="MJ"&MID(A1,LEN(A1)-7,7)
```

The `MID` function extracts a substring from within a longer string.

Comment: @Chronocidal not if you also want to avoid the rightmost character.

Comment: Since `EAN` should be 13-digits it could also be `="MJ"&MID(A1,6,7)`